# Use Geforce 210 only as output

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

On my work computer I have one to few HDMI outputs, so I am looking at adding a cheap graphics card, just for that reason.
Currently I use the HD 4600 in my i7.

I found that the cheapest graphics card with my required port configuration is the Geforce 210, which is significantly worse than the HD 4600 when it comes to performance.

So my question is, can I use the Geforce 210 as an HDMI output while using the HD 4600 to do the rendering? I don't need much graphics performance, since all I do on this computer is program and use Chrome, but I would really dislike it if adding hardware would decrease my computer's performance.

Comment: I think it's [duplicate question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/is-it-possible-to-use-different-cuda-capable-graphic-cards-to-render-simultaneou)

Comment: I don't think so, since your question is about CUDA cards and the answer says that it's possible to use multiple cards as long as you don't mix manufacturers. But I am asking specifically about mixing Nvidia and Intel.